# End of the month for every month

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, userform

In a user form in excel, using vba, I need to find the end of the month.For example my start date is 01.01.2015 and the end date will be automatically 31.01.2015.I try using this code:

```
Private Function dhLastDayInMonth(Optional dtmDate As Date = 0) As Date
    ' Return the last day in the specified month.

If dtmDate = 0 Then
        ' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
        ' the current date.
        dtmDate = Date
End If

dhLastDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(dtmDate), _
     Month(dtmDate) + 1, 0)

End Function
```

but this code only returns the end of February.
Example:
start date:01.01.2015 my code returns 28.02.2015
or start date: 05.02.2015 my code returns 28.02.2015

The seconde code line is to edit the text box to insert the end date

```
Private Sub txtEDate_Change()

If txtEDate.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox "You must enter a Date! "
    Exit Sub
End If

If txtEDate.TextLength = 2 Or txtEDate.TextLength = 5 Then
    txtEDate.Text = txtEDate.Text + "."
End If

If txtEDate.TextLength = 2 Or txtEDate.TextLength = 5 Then
txtEDate.Text = txtEDate.Text + "DD/MM/YYYY"
End If

txtEDate.Text = dhLastDayInMonth()

End Sub
```

Comment: Which is apparently because the `dtmDate = Date` line always executes in your case? Anyhow try the [built-in solution](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/EOMONTH-function-1525129b-fafb-44fc-90cd-4bea29ddda57).

Comment: Agree with @Gserg. Try double checking your input. If it is how you've written it, I don't think Excel or VBA recognize that format as a Date.

Comment: I tested your code and couldn't reproduce your issue. The code worked as expected.

Comment: My problems is that the code only returns the end of February but I also need the end of January, March etc.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. Please show some example input, desired output, current output, and point out how the current output differs from the desired. [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) always helps.

Comment: You never pass the parameter to the function, what else do you expect? The `dtmDate = Date` always executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define the year and month as *inputs* to get the last date in the month:

```
Public Function LastDayInMonth(dIn As Date) As Date
    LastDayInMonth = DateSerial(Year(dIn), Month(dIn) + 1, 0)
End Function
```

will give the last date in some month, but only if **dIn** has the proper value.

Clearly you should **MsgBox** *dtmDate* at the top of your UDF.